# Unable to Hide Page Action Button in Firefox 57

Tags: css, firefox

I was wanting to remove the Page Action button in Firefox's url bar, so I added the following line to my `userChrome.css` file:

```
#urlbar-page-action-button {display:none !important;}
```

However, nothing happened. How can I accomplish what I'm attempting?

I'm using Firefox Nightly `version 57.0a1` on a `Macbook`.

Comment: Did you do that while Firefox was running?

Comment: No, I did quit Firefox before updating the file.

Comment: OK, just checking. Ehm, how does one examine the chrome in Firefox exactly? I see nowhere in the tools where you can look at these controls. (Sorry, I'm spoiled with SeaMonkey's DOM inspector.)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. I don't know of a way to inspect it. There was an addon called DOM Inspector, but it only works with Firefox 49 and below.

Comment: Figured out how to inspect the chrome. You go to Tools > Web Developer > Browser Toolbox. Turns out it's called page-action, not page action button.

Comment: Good find. Now for people who (like me) didn't have the "Browser Toolbox" menu item, you must check the "Enable  browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" and "Enable remote debugging" boxes in the Toolbox options first, then it will show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `#urlbar-page-action-button` to `.urlbar-page-action`.

Comment: Wow!  Is this really the only way to get rid of that thing?!!  Nothing hidden in `about:config` or something?  (Not only doesn't it have "view page source" there's not a single useful option.  bookmark and pocket are already default buttons to the right, copy-pasting a link isn't rocket science and if I want a screenshot I'll hit prtscr button thanks...ugh)

Comment: If I use `.urlbar-page-action {display:none !important;}` I can disable *three dot button* in the URL bar, **but** I will hide bookmark star button **too**. Is there a way to keep bookmark but hide three dot ?

Comment: @mattia.b89 `#pageActionButton { display: none !important; }`

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble with your solution.  It seems `#` is the selector for id, not class... etc.

You can modify the `userChrome.css` file in `<userprofile>/chrome/userChome.css`.  Verify your profile directory locations with `about:profiles`.

Here's the content of my newly formed `userChrome.css` file:

```
/* Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct functioning */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

/* -- Test to see if this file is loaded correctly -- */
/* * {background-color:red !important;} /* *emphasis* important, '!' isn't NOT in CSS */

/*
 * HTML element to hide:  
 * <image xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" 
 * id="pageActionButton" class="urlbar-icon urlbar-page-action" role="button"
 * tooltiptext="Page actions" onmousedown="BrowserPageActions.mainButtonClicked(event);"
 * />
 *
 * element: image
 * id: pageActionButton
 * class: urlbar-icon urlbar-page-action
 */

image#pageActionButton {display:none !important;}
image.urlbar-page-action {display:none !important;}
                   /* who knows, maybe we get lucky and they change only one. */
```

Once done, you should have gotten rid of the new Firefox 57.0 hamburger ellipsis button built into the address bar with no "Remove from Address Bar" option that all the other buttons (pocket, favorite) have.

Answer (score 0):

Because I want to keep the bookmark star, here's what I've found at https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/7vhcew/how_to_remove_page_actions_button_three/ :

```
#pageActionButton { display: none !important; }
```